# Deserializar un archivo

Tags: java, deserialize

Necesito deserializar varios archivos con extensión `.cat`, pero no sé qué clase manejan.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```java
import java.io. * ;

public class deserializacion {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    /*---------------------------
           DESERIALIZACIÓN
    ----------------------------*/

    try {
      // Ruta del archivo a deserializar
      FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Rosa Ma\\Desktop\\JAVA\\CiaTab08.cat");

      // Objeto
      ObjectInputStream Object_input = new ObjectInputStream(file);

      I_DONT_KNOW_THE_CLASS[] object = (I_DONT_KNOW_THE_CLASS[]) Object_input.readObject(); //Solo me falta ver que clase maneja
      Object_input.close();

      for (I_DONT_KNOW_THE_CLASS: objeto_recuperado) {
        System.out.println(e);
      }

    } catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola, un archivo con una extensión ".x" por ejemplo .cat indica que dicho archivo tiene un formato determinado, es decir, sigue ciertas reglas a la hora de escribir cosas en el archivo. Hasta donde sé, no existe una clase nativa de Java que te permita leer un archivo .cat . Vas a tener que investigar que formato tienen esos archivos y crear una clase que te proporcione métodos útiles para hacer lo que sea que quieras hacer con esos archivos

Comment: Como puedo saber que formato ocupan dichos archivos?

Comment: Acá hay algo de información sobre los archivos .cat https://fileinfo.com/extension/cat#:~:text=File%20used%20by%20the%20Windows,verifying%20new%20software%20update%20files.